# Show progressBar while function is running Pyside2

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyside2

I'm working on Pyside2, python 3.8, windows 10

I have an app that parses a file and show data in QtableView. What I'm trying to implement is a Dialog Window with only one button, the only purpose of this dialog window is to give a minimalistic and simple view to the user, where he can first select the file to be parsed and have a Loading progress barwhile the LoadData() function is runned. The Home Dialog should only be hidden/closed when the parsing is done.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,  Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, file_name,parent=None):
        """
        ..
        __init__ code lines
        """
        self.change_val = QtCore.Signal(int)
        self.change_val[int].connect(self.set_progress_val)
        self.progress = QtWidgets.QProgressDialog('loading...', 'cancel', 0, 100, self)
        self.progress.show()
        self.LoadData(d.path)
    
    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def set_progress_val(self, val):
        self.progress.setValue(val)

    def LoadData(self, file_path):
        
        """
        Parsing lines of code
        ..
        self.change_val.emit(30)
        ..
        ..
        self.change_val.emit(60)
        ..
        ..
        """
        self.progress.hide()
        #Parsing finished -> show the mainWindow
        self.show()

class HomeDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, home_dialog.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(HomeDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.openB6.clicked.connect(self.get_file_name)

    def get_file_name(self):
        file_name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open config file',
                                                            dir=path.join("/"),
                                                            filter="B6 (*.b6)")
        if not file_name[0]:
            return None
        else:
            self.path = file_name
            self.accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(ProxyStyle())
    d = HomeDialog()
    if d.exec_():
        mainWin = MainWindow(file_name=d.path)
        mainWin.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm getting the follwoing error on `self.change_val[int].connect(self.set_progress_val)` line :

```
'str' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signals are not declared in the class constructor or in the methods but in the static part:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,  Ui_MainWindow):
    change_val = QtCore.Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, file_name,parent=None):
        """
        ..
        __init__ code lines
        """
        self.change_val[int].connect(self.set_progress_val)
        self.progress = QtWidgets.QProgressDialog('loading...', 'cancel', 0, 100, self)
        self.progress.show()
        self.LoadData(d.path)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed it was the self which I was missing.

My ProgressDialog doesn't update, it freezes, any idea how to fix that please ? 

thanks again

Comment: update: I added QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents() in my set_progress_val slot. In case It'd help anyone